# Getting Notepad++ DBGp XDEBUG plugin to work on Windows 7 to remote server

Tags: php, windows-7, notepad++, xdebug

I'm current running Notepad++ on windows 7 as my primary coding environment. I'm currently looking to debug PHP using the xdebug plugin for Notepad++, DBGp.

Xdebug is set up on the remote server just fine (it's a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server running apache2 and PHP5). A colleague of mine is running Eclipse on SUSE linux and has Xdebug working just fine on it. However, no matter what configs I try I can't seem to get Xdebug working for me on Notepad++.

I have tried the following guides to get this working with no joy:

- http://amiworks.co.in/talk/debugging-php-using-xdebug-and-notepad-part-i/
- http://forum.uniformserver.com/index.php?showtopic=1354
- http://www.judiwa.com/2010/03/27/how-to-setup-bdgp-debugger-in-notepad-to-debug-php/
- http://lamp-dev.com/php-debugging-with-xdebug-dbgp-and-notepad-windows/35

The main problem with these guides seems to be that they assume people are running a local development environment, which I am not.

My current settings for the DBGp plugin are:

- remote server IP: {the server IP}
- IDE KEY: xdebug
- Remote Path: file://Z:/home/garryw/www/idp/650hoursSocialPortal/site
- Local Path: Z:

I have also tried:

- Remote Path: file:///home/garryw/www/idp/650hoursSocialPortal/site

with no luck either. I have tried so many combinations of Remote Path, Local Path etc... that I'm not sure what else to try now.

On the remote server xdebug is set to map to port 9002 for my user so in PuTTY I set localhost:9000 to map to {server IP}:9002 but this also had no affect....

I'm now incredibly frustrated and can think of nowhere else to turn to for advice... Any suggestions?

Comment: as clarification the Z: referenced a few times above refers to a WebDrive map I have to the remote server.

Comment: Start setting up the debugger in a local setup. It's okay you do that commandline style, no need for a webserver. If you get it up and running locally, you will have it much easier to setup it on the remote site.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
When I added the xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1 variable in the file / etc/php5/apache2/php.ini worked.

```
; xdebug configuration starts
zend_extension="/opt/packages/xdebug-2.2.4/modules/xdebug.so"
; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
; xdebug configuration ends
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your putty tunnel the other way around, there is a description here: http://drck.me/xdebug-fw-8r4

Comment: tried this but also didn't work. I think it's something to do with the local and remote location settings but I'm buggered if I can figure it out...

Comment: btw, I know the tunnel's working as I can telnet to localhost:9000 just fine

Answer (score 0):

As long as your IP + IDEkey setting is correct, Notepad++ will capture the communication with XDebug and you can check it by clicking on the DBG button. If it is empty, you probably have an issue with the port or some other part of the Xdebug config. If it is not empty, you probably have wrong path settings - you can check the messages from Xdebug to see what path it sends. The correct setting is probably `file:///home/garryw/www/` (remote) / `Z:\home\garryw\www\` (local).